# If A bean is created using @Bean tag then we can create two beans. How is it singleton per applicatonContext

Tags: java, spring, singleton

Here if StudentInfo class is prototype then it will create two separate references which is Ok but in case of singleton also it is creating two beans naming student and student1 then it breaks the rule of singleton per application context. If I am missing something please let me know. How can we create a singleton bean per application context in this case?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.spring")
public class AnnotationConfiguration {
    @Bean(name="student")
    public StudentInfo info() {
        return new StudentInfo("girraj","gupta");
    }
    @Bean(name="student1")
    public StudentInfo info1() {
        return new StudentInfo("girraj1","gupta1");
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think there is rule in spring that Application context must contains singleton beans

Comment: If two beans are equal it doesn't mean singleton

Comment: Yes right but if we want to create a singleton bean and want to restrict that no body is allowed to create it again. how can we do this in annotation based?

Comment: Then why not declare that class with @Component and leave that to spring

Answer (score 2):

From [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

> When a bean is a singleton, only one shared instance of the bean will be managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition will result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring container.

In your example, you are creating two different beans of the same class. Since the scope is specific to the bean, it has nothing to do with the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is a two-step process that consists of:

- Define a bean.
- Inject the bean.

When you declare a bean definition with @Bean annotation, you declare a recipe for creating actual instances of the class defined by that bean definition. It means that you can create many object instances from a single recipe.

When JavaConfig encounters such a method, it will execute that method and register the return value as a bean within Spring IoC container.

In your example, you declared two bean definitions. So both is registered as a separate bean within Spring IoC container. For singleton bean, Spring will intercept any calls to it and ensure that the bean produced by that method is returned rather than allowing it to be invoked again.

Please refer [Bean Scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) and [Basic bean configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts)

Answer (score 0):

> Here if StudentInfo class is prototype ...

It does not matter if `StudentInfo` is a prototype. What you are actually doing is that you instantiate a `StudentInfo` with the `new` operator, like:

```
return new StudentInfo("girraj1","gupta1");
```

The actual bean definition is the factory method you have made and you have two of those so two beans.

So - and in other way around - when you inject a bean that actually is instance of `StudentInfo` you do not inject `StudentInfo` but a bean named **student** or **student1**, like:

```
@Qualifier("student1")
@Autowired
private StudentInfo studentInfo;
```

And student1, student they might both be singletons.

Comment: Yes. you are right but can we restrict application context to create only one singleton bean per application context means if somebody tries to create the object again it should not allow or it will return you same reference.